# Mongodb exception failed to get next data vb.net

Tags: vb.net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a program to get data from database mongodb but I failed to get next data

This code

```
Dim listOfBusiness = New Generic.List(Of Business)
Dim mongo As MongoServer = MongoServer.Create(otherComputerToServerSafeUpdate)
mongo.Connect()
Dim db = mongo.GetDatabase("namedatabase")
Using mongo.RequestStart(db)
    Dim collection = db.GetCollection(Of BsonDocument)("tablebusiness")
    Dim queryPlaces = query.WithinRectangle("LongitudeLatitude", (Longitude - minimumBlock), (Latitude - minimumBlock), (Longitude + minimumBlock), (Latitude + minimumBlock))
    Dim ListCollectionBusinessCursor = collection.Find(queryPlaces)
    For Each ReturnedDocument In ListCollectionBusinessCursor
        Dim aBusiness = New Business(ReturnedDocument)
        listOfBusiness.Add(aBusiness)
    Next ReturnedDocument   'Got exception here
End Using
```

This  is  my exception

Mongodb query exception

```
QueryFailure flag was assertion db\key.cpp:409 (response was { "$err" : "assertion db\\key.cpp:409" })
```

I try  queryplace in mongodb shell, I  got 13 result

```
Queryplace="{ "LongitudeLatitude" : { "$within" : { "$box" : [[-80.293072110482868, 26.29], [-80.213072110482855, 26.369999999999997]] } } }"
```

What is the problem and why does this happen? It happens only once in a while.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error message come up and the solution was repairing the database.

`mongod --repair`